# How to resolve the issue of Python being unable to call my own C++ library?

Tags: python, c++

I want to compile and use a C++ code in Python. I have two files in a folder, namely **trans.cpp** and **setup.py**. I can successfully install this third-party library, but I'm unable to call the functions inside it. I would like to know where I went wrong.
trans.cpp

```
#include <torch/extension.h>
#include <vector>
void torch_tensor2vector(torch::Tensor &output) {
    int* ptr = (int *)output.data_ptr();
}
PYBIND11_MODULE(TORCH_EXTENSION_NAME, m) {
    m.def("torch_tensor2vector",
          &torch_tensor2vector,
          "trans kernel warpper");
}
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CUDAExtension, CppExtension
setup(
    name="self_sample_full",
    include_dirs=["include"],
    ext_modules=[
        CppExtension("trans",["pytorch/trans.cpp"],),
    ],
    cmdclass={
        "build_ext": BuildExtension
    },
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

use.py

```
import self_sample_full
output = torch.empty(n).to(device="cuda:0")
self_sample_full.torch_tensor2vector(output)
```

error:

```
AttributeError: module 'self_sample_full' has no attribute 'torch_tensor2vector'
```

Comment: I think you have to include the #Python.h file in you C++ code, see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html)